# Define interceptors for multiple clients

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I'm using multiple Axios clients.

```js
const api1Client = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API1_HOST,
    // ...
});
const api2Client = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API2_HOST,
    // ...
});
// ...
```

There are some for which I need to specify common interceptors, and I'd like to avoid repeating the definitions.

```js
api1Client.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    doingSomeMysteriousStuff();
    return config;
}, error => {
    doingSomeOtherMysteriousStuff();
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

api2Client.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    doingSomeMysteriousStuff();
    return config;
}, error => {
    doingSomeOtherMysteriousStuff();
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

I could still do this, but still too much repeats for me :)

```
api1Client.interceptors.request.use(
    doingSomeMysteriousStuffHandler,
    doingSomeOtherMysteriousStuffHandler
);
api2Client.interceptors.request.use(
    doingSomeMysteriousStuffHandler,
    doingSomeOtherMysteriousStuffHandler
);
```

How can I factorize that without specifying the interceptors globally ?

Comment: please refer to this [article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/setting-up-axios-interceptors-for-all-http-calls-in-an-application-71bc2c636e4e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with based on @RyanLe & @Bergi suggestions, thanks guys.

```
[api1Client, api2Client].forEach((client) => {
    client.interceptors.request.use(
        (config) => {
            doingSomeMysteriousStuff();
            return config;
        },
        (error) => {
            doingSomeOtherMysteriousStuff();
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );
});
```

This allows me to process not only interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

**You probably want to create a function for that**

Something similar to this:

```
function addInterceptor(...apiClients) {
  apiClients.forEach((client) => {
    client.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        doingSomeMysteriousStuff();
        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        doingSomeOtherMysteriousStuff();
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  });
}

addInterceptor(api1Client, api2Client);
```

Comment: Rather make `addInterceptor` take only a single client as argument, then call `[api1Cleint, api2Client].forEach(addInterceptor);`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more extendible to put dynamic client array to arguments?

Comment: No. Unless you have to call the function multiple times, there's no point in putting the code into a function. And you don't have multiple dynamic client arrays here. Also the function that takes only a single client is more extensible, since it means you can add extra parameters to it in the future.